# How to change an Imageview position randomly per running the app

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and I want to make an android app that has a random position for an image view every time the app is run.  This way the image shows in a different horizontal position per running the app. I have looked online and found questions that seem to help me but I cant get it when I try. Here is my onCreate method. Everything seems to work the want I want except the part where I commented out which is what I have found online.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    rotation = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    sm.registerListener(this, rotation, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);


    final Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.y;
    height = size.x;

    //=============This code is from what I have found online====================
    final ImageView zombie1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zombie1);
    //zombie1.postInvalidate();
    MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) zombie1.getLayoutParams();
    int rndInt = rnd.nextInt(width);
    params.setMargins(rndInt, 30, rndInt + zombie1.getWidth(), zombie1.getHeight());
    zombie1.setLayoutParams(params);
    //===========================================================================


    ScaleAnimation sa = new ScaleAnimation(1, 7, 1, 7, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
    sa.setDuration(5000);
    sa.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            zombie1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

   zombie1.startAnimation(sa);      
}
```

If you need to see my activity_main.xml here it is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<ImageView
    android:id = "@+id/zombie1"
    android:layout_width = "75dp"
    android:layout_height = "75dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical = "true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
    android:layout_marginTop = "30dp"
    android:src = "@drawable/finalzombie1" 
    android:visibility = "visible"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be much appreciated and Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the problem you are getting in this code? The code seems to be fine

Comment: The position stays the same every time I run the app